# Convert a @State into a Publisher

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I want to use a `@State` variable both for the UI and for computing a value.

For example, let's say I have a `TextField` bound to `@State var userInputURL: String = "https://"`. How would I take that `userInputURL` and connect it to a publisher so I can `map` it into a `URL`.

Pseudo code:

```swift
$userInputURL.publisher()
      .compactMap({ URL(string: $0) })
      .flatMap({ URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral).dataTaskPublisher(for: $0).assertNoFailure() })
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't convert @state to publisher, but you can use ObservableObject instead.

```
import SwiftUI

final class SearchStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var query: String = ""

    func fetch() {
        $query
            .map { URL(string: $0) }
            .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0) }
            .sink { print($0) }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var store = SearchStore()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("type something...", text: $store.query)
            Button("search") {
                self.store.fetch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `onChange(of:)` to respond to `@State` changes.

```
struct MyView: View {

  @State var userInputURL: String = "https://"

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("search here", text: $userInputURL)
    }
    .onChange(of: userInputURL) { _ in
      self.fetch()
    }
  }

  func fetch() {
    print("changed", userInputURL)
    // ...
  }
}
```

Output:

```
changed https://t
changed https://ts
changed https://tsr
changed https://tsrs
changed https://tsrst
```

Comment: But the question is about: `Convert a @State into a Publisher` not using `@State` or `onChange(of:)`

Comment: This seems like the better solution in my case than the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

The latest beta has changed how variables are published so I don't think that you even want to try. Making ObservableObject classes is pretty easy but you then want to add a publisher for your own use:

```swift
class ObservableString: Combine.ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    let publisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    var string: String {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
        didSet { publisher.send(string) }
    }

    init(_ string: String = "") { self.string = string }
}
```

Instead of `@State` variables you use `@ObservableObject` and remember to access the property string directly rather than use the magic that @State uses.

Answer (score -4):

After iOS 14.0, you can access to Publisher.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var text: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text ?? "")
            .onReceive($text.wrappedValue.publisher) { _ in
                let publisher1: Optional<String>.Publisher = $text.wrappedValue.publisher
                
                // ... or
                
                let publisher2: Optional<String>.Publisher = _text.wrappedValue.publisher
            }
    }
}
```